# Is it okay to say "with self as foo:" in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x, with-statement

Inside a class method of a Python class, is it alright to use

```
with self as foo:
  pass # more stuff here ...
```

(or even just `with self:`) or will this cause some issues? The documentation doesn't seem to put any limitations on it and so far I didn't observe any erroneous behavior. But of course this could be limited to my exact Python version or use case.

And yes, the class *is* a context manager.

Comment: I would think so but don't do it within either of that class's `__enter__` or `__exit__` methods.

Comment: There isn't anything special about `self` or being inside a method, can't think of any reason why this would be a problem except for what Dan D. mentions.